# Macro to copy paste range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CPRow()

Range("D14:K14").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("D15").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
 End Sub
```

i want to add code to do the following:

1- if the sheet name begins with a number then copy the range (D14:K14) and paste it in Range (D15:K15) as Values.

2- Go to next sheet and do the same, and stop when there is a sheet with no number or until sheet name starts with a letter.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No i,m just asking if there is a macro that can copy paste a range of cells in each sheet of the workbook. i dont know how to write code yet i can only alter to take a another range. Not looking for 3rd party engine or anything like that

Comment: Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how we can help you better.

Comment: i just added my code up there, hope that helps Mr Scott Holtzman.

Comment: @R.excel form which sheet do you want to copy the `Range("D14:K14")` ? what is the name of the sheet that you want to copy from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will copy `Range("D14:K14")` form `Worksheets("Sheet1")` (modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name), and paste it to all worksheet's that their Name start with a number.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CPRow()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim ShttoCopy As Worksheet

Set ShttoCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- modify "Sheet1" to the sheet you want to copy Range("D14:K14") from

For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If IsNumeric(Left(Sht.Name, 1)) Then
        ShttoCopy.Range("D14:K14").Copy
        Sht.Range("D15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next Sht

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai, Appreciate your help. ill explain more. i have around 80 sheets, each of those sheets represent a job#. every month i roll over this excel file and need to copy paste data of last month from D14:K14 to D15.   I Tried your code but its taking Sheet1 and copy paste to all sheets.

Comment: @R.excel it's pasting to all sheets that start with a Numeric like you wanted, no ?

Comment: Let me clarify more, i want the macro to go to first sheet thats numeric and copy the Range("D14:K14") paste in D15 then go to next sheet copy Range("D14:K14") paste in D15 then next sheet  and so on, keep it looping until no more numeric sheets in workbook. Hope i explained it well.  thanks

Comment: @R.excel  and this exactly what this code does, exactly

Comment: Hi Shai, thank you i modified your code and now it worked for me. i updated the answer above to show the correct code .